# How to set up django user options for generic models

Tags: python, django, django-models, generic-foreign-key

I have a Profile model for custom user data:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False)
    # more stuff...
```

I also have a Notifications app that allows models to send notifications and emails to users.

I want users to have the option to turn on or off different notifications, but I DON'T want to add a massive list of boolean fields to the Profile like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False)
    send_model1_notice1 = models.BooleanField()
    send_model1_email1 = models.BooleanField()
    send_model1_notice2 = models.BooleanField()
    send_model1_email2 = models.BooleanField()
    send_model2_notice1 = models.BooleanField()
    send_model2_email1 = models.BooleanField()
    send_model3_notice1 = models.BooleanField()
    send_model3_email1 = models.BooleanField()
    # etc...
```

where modelx is some model or some other app that is the origin of the notification, and noticex/emailx is some specific cause for notification.

I was thinking a more sustainable way of doing this would be to create a ProfileOptions model that external models could use to define their own notifications settings.

This way, when I add a new app/model, I could link its notification sources to the ProfileOptions model somehow and have these options to turn them on or off magically appear in the user's profile.

Does this make sense? If so, is it possible? If so is it a good idea? and if so, what structure should I use to connect the models, ProfileOptions, and the user's Profile?

Obviously I'm hoping for an answer to the last question, but I don't want to rule out the possibility that the answer to the others might be "no".

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have a separate `Notification` model which links the two:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Notification(models.Model):
    # Foreign key to user profile
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)

    # Generic foreign key to whatever model you want.
    src_model_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    src_model_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    src_model = GenericForeignKey('src_model_content_type', 'src_model_object_id')

    # Notification on or off. Alternatively, only store active notifications.
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

This approach would let you handle an arbitrary number of source models for notifications (each with an arbitrary number of notifications), without trying to squeeze all the notification information into your user profile.

Comment: I'm confused, I already have a `Notification` model (as mentioned).  You mean this could be the `ProfileOptions` model I mentioned?

Comment: Your question says you have a "Notifications app" - not that there is a model - many apps have no models :-). In any case, yes, this could be your `ProfileOption` model that acts as a link between `Profile` and some arbitrary models defined elsewhere - assuming all your options have the same type (e.g., boolean on/off).